# Three.js WebXR(AR) place object upright on a wall (how to rotate properly)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, augmented-reality, webxr

I'm trying to place a painting upright on a wall (respectively a vertical aligned surface) but struggling with the correct rotation. To keep the example small I removed the painting stuff and am transferring the problem to the reticle. As you can see in the two last pictures, the reticle is pretty much twisted when placed on a wall.

My goal is to have the local x axis always parallel to the floor and the local z axis pointing downwards.

Does this have anything to do with the side fact that the z axis of the reticle is always facing at camera when focused on the floor?

I tried to remove the unwanted rotation with reverse rotation and change the euler order but it seems to me to be a more generic problem. Is anyone having an idea how to fix this? I'm not able to solve it or find a proper solution, appreciate any help.

I got the main code from here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webxr_ar_hittest.html

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { ARButton } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton'

var camera
var scene 
var renderer
var arbutton
var controller
var reticle

var hitTestSource = null
var hitTestSourceRequested = false

init()
renderer.setAnimationLoop(render);

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.xr.enabled = true;

    arbutton = ARButton.createButton(renderer, { 
        requiredFeatures: ['hit-test'],
        optionalFeatures: ['dom-overlay'],
        domOverlay: { root: document.getElementById('arOverlay') } 
    })
    document.body.appendChild(arbutton);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 20);

    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xbbbbff, 1);
    light.position.set(0.5, 1, 0.25);
    scene.add(light);

    reticle = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(0.15, 0.2, 32).rotateX(-Math.PI/2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
    reticle.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    reticle.visible = false;
    scene.add(reticle);
    reticle.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(0.5));
    reticle.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(0.1, 0.1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()))

    controller = renderer.xr.getController(0);
    scene.add(controller);

    scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1));
}

function render(timestamp, frame) {
    if(frame){
        var referenceSpace = renderer.xr.getReferenceSpace();
        var session = renderer.xr.getSession();

        if (hitTestSourceRequested === false) {
            session.requestReferenceSpace('viewer').then(function (referenceSpace) {
                session.requestHitTestSource({ space: referenceSpace }).then(function (source) {
                    hitTestSource = source;
                });
            });
            session.addEventListener('end', function () {
                hitTestSourceRequested = false;
                hitTestSource = null;
            });
            hitTestSourceRequested = true;
        }

        if (hitTestSource) {
            var hitTestResults = frame.getHitTestResults(hitTestSource);
            if (hitTestResults.length) {
                var hit = hitTestResults[0];
                reticle.visible = true;
                reticle.matrix.fromArray(hit.getPose(referenceSpace).transform.matrix);

                // TODO apply some additional rotation here

            } else {
                reticle.visible = false;
            }
        }
    
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From my limited experience with XR, this should be handled by the AR engine, which should be gathering orientation cues from the environment and your device sensors. That said, your input (the pallets) may be confusing it. Does it do the same thing when you aim it as a smooth regular surface, like the wall?

Comment: Yes same issue when aimed on a real wall. The paletts are just recognized better.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a fix where I am rotating the reticle around the y axis by its angle to the xz plane.

```
let aX = new Vector3()
reticle.matrix.extractBasis(aX, new Vector(), new Vector())

let yUp = new Vector3(0,1,0)
let alpha = Math.asin(aX.dot(yUp)) 
                    
let m = new Matrix4()
m.makeRotationY(Math.PI+alpha) 

reticle.matrix.multiply(m)
```